# Java.lang.ClassCastException error and app crashes

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Error Log I'm stuck here I've tried many solutions but same error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.beauty.fashion.style.KidsNavigationDrawerActivity cannot be cast to com.beauty.fashion.style.interfaces.UpdateOrderTotal
        at com.beauty.fashion.style.adapters.CheckoutAdapter.<init>(CheckoutAdapter.java:38)
        at com.beauty.fashion.style.fragment.OrderConfirmationFragment.onCreateView(OrderConfirmationFragment.java:109)
```

This is my android code

```
 public CheckoutAdapter(Context context, List<ProductModel> list) {

        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        callback = (UpdateOrderTotal) context;  //This is line 38 of CheckoutAdapter
        helper = new FashionDbHelper(context);
        utils = new CartUtils(context);
    }
```

This is where I'm getting products to cart list and app is crashing

```
if (utils.getCartList().getValue() != null) {
            cartList.addAll(utils.getCartList().getValue());
            if (cartList != null && cartList.size() > 0) {
                linearEmptyCart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                cvGrandTotal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                adapter = new CheckoutAdapter(getActivity(), cartList); //This is line 109 
                rvConfirmOrder.setAdapter(adapter);
                rvConfirmOrder.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                calculateTotal(cartList);
            } else {
                linearEmptyCart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cvGrandTotal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else {
            cvGrandTotal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            linearEmptyCart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `KidsNavigationDrawerActivity` to implement `UpdateOrderTotal` interface.

Something like this:

```
public class KidsNavigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UpdateOrderTotal {

// your Activity code here

}
```

Comment: KidsNavigationDrawerActivity is my HomePage activity where products are displayed when ever I select any product and add it to cart it adds successfully but when I click on My cart to check my cart then app crashes and the above error log comes up

Answer (score -1):

I've done it by myself after implementing interface to KidsNavigationDrawer activity